# I need help to merge two profiles I have

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, merge-accounts

I need help to merging my two profiles. I removed the email from one of them, so now I don't have any access to it.

I was trying with *Help Center* → *Contact*, but unfortunately I get the following error:

> "We can't merge until we have links to both profiles; please add the missing URL and try again"

Even when I fill in the URL field (I was logged into the account listed in "Your profile link"):

[image]

I get an error!

[image]

Comment: Did you fill in all the [fields in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSihR.png) before submitting? The first 2 should be auto filled if you are logged in to one of the accounts.

Comment: When you use your real name... it becomes kind of easy for others to just send emails to hotmail and gmail variants using that name as the base. The people who are out to abuse won't generally care if something bounces or not or reaches the wrong person. There is more to personal privacy and security than only hiding your email, especially in this day and age.

Comment: To clarify, given that the images and text in the question don't make it certain as to what's happening: You entered a valid profile link for **both** profiles, as shown in the first image. Then, after you clicked "Submit", the URL you provided in "Your other profile link" was automatically cleared and you received the error shown in the second image. Is that correct?

Comment: While it is useful to us to have the correct reason so that you can potentially go through the self-merge process, since you are having trouble submitting this form, please use the "other" option instead and explain the issue you're having with requesting a merge. The Support team will be able to assist you with the merge.

Comment: @Catija I should have, but failed to, add a [meta-tag:bug] tag here prior to adding the [meta-tag:status-review] tag. While we don't know for sure, it appears that in addition to the [meta-tag:support] issue, there's also a bug with the validation of the merge form after the user clicked "Submit". The bug, may, be the result of the current state of the OP's accounts, potentially the part where the OP said "One of them I removed the email". We really don't know without more testing.

Comment: @Makyen Even if there's a bug - if it's only a problem with this one case and not a general bug that many people trying to merge are running into, the Support team is still the best place to start as they can explain what's going on in a more clear and detailed way - an answer here would require us to be more general about how we respond. And sending a contact form can still lead to a bug being submitted for investigation, similarly to a status-reviewed post. :) Just a different way to get a dev to poke at something.

Comment: Potentially related MSE report (though the accounts have already been merged in that case): [Can't open a ticket for merging accounts; Error occurs even though all fields are included](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389841/335251)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As referenced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392952/344828), I've fixed this issue. Please let me know if you're continuing to experience any problems, and thanks for reporting the issue!