# I lost all my reputation and badges when I updated my password, so where do I get that fixed?

Tags: support, accounts, duplicate-accounts

I went on vacation, came back to a dead laptop. When I got a new one I tried to log on to Stack Overflow and could not remember my password. So I requested a password reset. Got the email, changed the password and logged in. HOWEVER, Stack had created me as a new user with a new userid number, so I lost all my reputation and badges (not that I had all the many, but they were hard-earned).

How do I get this fixed?

Comment: @OP You can visit here https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/ to get help with account issues.

Comment: *Stack had created me as a new user"* No it didn't, the account you are posting from is over 6 years old. I suspect, however, that you had *two* accounts on [so] and have access the *wrong* account. If you find a post that belong to you previously, you'll likely see that the account still has the reputation it did before.

Comment: Related: "[I need help to merge two profiles I have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426064/3773011)"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two accounts. You requested a password reset on the wrong account. You didn't create a new account now as the account you are currently using is a couple of years old.

You can use [contact us](https://stackoverflow.co/company/contact/) form to request a merger of your two accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the actual help. Unfortunately, every time I hit Submit on the Merge Accounts page it clears my "other account link" filed then errors out saying I have to enter the other account's URL (which I have done numerous times now).

Comment: @RichardTaylor Would you like me to submit it on your behalf?

Comment: @RichardTaylor Unfortunately, there appears to be a bug on that page, which has been reported, but not yet fixed (see "[I need help to merge two profiles I have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426064/3773011)"). I'd suggest that you submit a contact request using the "other" "other" selection and include the URLs to the accounts in the free-form text. I'd be sure to mention the bug in trying to submit the request using the "correct" selection, so they know why you didn't use the "correct" contact method and don't just tell you to use that.

Comment: @RichardTaylor A moderator can submit a request for you, but it probably would result in the Community Managers contacting you to confirm that a merger is what you want (which might take longer than you submitting the request via the contact form). If you want us to submit that for you, we're happy to do so. To ask for us to do so, please raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag. Please include the URL to at least the other account (or a question or answer by that account). We can *guess* which account, and I'd be very surprised if we were wrong, but it's better to be *certain*.

Comment: @RichardTaylor Another alternative would be to log out of this current account and then try to do the password recovery process with your other account, if you can remember the email address or credentials you used with that account.

Comment: @RichardTaylor: Regarding "*Thanks for the actual help*" -- did you feel any of the comments to your original meta question weren't helpful? If so, how so?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By "actual" I meant the inclusion of a direct link to where the solution could be had (even though it doesn't work) instead of just saying "request a merge from Stack" (which I never would have found)

Comment: @Makyen I will submit an "other" request -- thanks for suggesting it